# Como guardar datos cifrados de forma segura en Android?

Tags: android, sqlite

Estoy haciendo una aplicacion de Chat y quiero guardar las conversaciones de los usuarios en sus telefonos para poder acceder a ellas cuando se este offline, pero no se de que forma guardar esas conversaciones, tengo entendido que se pueden guardar en SharedPreferences, archivos de texto(.txt), archivos .DAT, sqLite, etc... pero  no se cual es la mas recomendable ni cual de estas usan las principales apps de mensajeria instantanea como Whatsapp, Telegram o Facebook Messenger y quiero que los datos se guarden encriptados para que no se pueda acceder a ellos desde apps externas

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Si el dispositivo del usuario es root da igual donde guardes la información porque el usuario podrá acceder a los ficheros de base de datos o los de Shared preferences o cualquier archivos que se almacene en el carpetas de la App.

La encriptación es fundamental para el cometido que quieres hacer para mantener la privacidad de las conversaciones. Yo te recomendaría utilizar la Base de Datos para el almacenamiento de las conversaciones, ya que te resultará más fácil acceder a la información que desees y puede almacenar un gran volumen de datos.

WhattsApp por ejemplo sino me equivoco utiliza Base de datos, de la cual va haciendo copias de seguridad todos los días y estas copias están encriptadas. Si entras con un gestor de archivos podrás ver dentro de la carpeta Whatsapp una carpeta llamada Databases en la que podrás ver la BD con el nombre msgstore.db.crypt12 y las copias de seguridad con nombre msgstore-año-mes-dia.1.db.crypt12. Telegram y Facebook Messenger no he investigado como gestionan esto.

Espero que te sirva de ayuda.

Comment: Muchas gracias ;)

Comment: De nada! Espero te sirva de algo

Answer (score 0):

Lo mejor es que cifres (y descifres al leerlos), puede ser con un algoritmo de cifrado por clave, te recomiendo que hagas tu propio algoritmo (busca operadores de bits para esto) y que cifres cada dato de la conversación (carácter, valor, etc) y que cifres el archivo (byte por byte) para un cifrado mas efectivo y la clave de cifrado puede ser generada por tu servidor